# Tag editor broken in "I want to work with"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, developer-story

When I view [my Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1269037) and try to edit the "I want to work with" tags, the editor seems broken: I can't scroll through the tags using the keyboard arrows or the mouse.

Chrome 68 on Linux.

[image: Tag editing broken]

Comment: [Probably the same bug reported](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16746/69850).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report! This should be fixed with our next production build.